# Joining and Aggregating a Large Number of Fact Tables Efficiently in Redshift

Tags: sql, database, amazon-redshift, data-warehouse

I have a number of (10M+ rows) fact tables in Redshift, each with a natural key `memberid` and each with a column `timestamp`. Let's say I have three tables: `transactions`, `messages`, `app_opens`, with `transactions` looking like this (all the other tables have similar structure):

| memberid | revenue | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 374893978 | 3.99 | 2021-02-08 18:34:01 |
| 374893943 | 7.99 | 2021-02-08 19:34:01 |

My goal is to create a daily per-memberid aggregation table that looks likes this, with a row for each memberid and date:

| memberid | date | daily_revenue | daily_app_opens | daily_messages |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 374893978 | 2021-02-08 | 4.95 | 31 | 45 |
| 374893943 | 2021-02-08 | 7.89 | 23 | 7 |

The SQL I'm currently using for this is the following, which involves unioning separate subqueries:

```
SELECT memberid,
       date,
       max(NVL(daily_revenue,0)) daily_revenue,
       max(NVL(daily_app_opens,0)) daily_app_opens,
       max(NVL(daily_messages,0)) daily_messages
FROM 
 (
 SELECT memberid,
        trunc(timestamp) as date,
        sum(revenue) daily_revenue,
        NULL AS daily_app_opens,
        NULL AS daily_messages
 FROM transactions
 GROUP BY 1,2

 UNION ALL

 SELECT memberid,
        trunc(timestamp) as date,
        NULL AS daily_revenue,
        count(*) daily_app_opens,
        NULL AS daily_messages
 FROM app_opens
 GROUP BY 1,2

 UNION ALL

 SELECT memberid,
        trunc(timestamp) as date,
        NULL AS daily_revenue,
        NULL AS daily_app_opens,
        count(*) daily_messages
 FROM messages
 GROUP BY 1,2
)
GROUP BY memberid, date
```

This works fine and produces the expected output, but I'm wondering if this is the most efficient way to carry out this kind of query. I have also using `FULL OUTER JOIN` in place of `UNION ALL`, but the performance is essentially identical.

What's the most efficient way to achieve this in Redshift?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the EXPLAIN plan would help as it would let us see what the most costly parts of the query are.  Based on a quick read of the SQL it looks pretty good.  The cost of scanning the fact tables is likely meaningful but this is a cost you have to endure.  If you can restrict the amount of data read with a where clause this can be reduced but doing this may not meet your needs.

One place that you should review is the distribution of these tables.  Since you are grouping by accountid having this as the distribution key will make this process faster.  Grouping will need bring rows of the same accountid value together, distributing on these values will greatly cut down on network traffic within the cluster.

At large data sizes and with everything else optimized I'd expect UNION ALL to out perform FULL OUTER JOIN but this will depend on a number of factors (like how much the data size is reduced by the accountid aggregation).  10M rows is not very big in Redshift terms (I have 160M rows of wide data on a minimal cluster) so I don't think you will see much difference between these plans at these sizes.